# setcookie in cookiemanager not working on Android

Tags: java, android, http, cookies, android-studio

I'm using cookiemanager in androidapp.
I called an instance of cookiemanager and tried to set cookies using cookiemanager.setcookie(url,string).

But my cookiemanager instance doesnot set any cookies. I tried checking every answer on SO, couldn't solve the problem. Anyone with ideas would be greatly helpful.

```
 public void syncCookieStoreToWebView() {
    PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = ReferenceHolder.getCookieStore();
    List<Cookie> cookies = myCookieStore.getCookies();

    final CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

    final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    if (! cookies.isEmpty()){

        //sync all the cookies in the httpclient with the webview by generating cookie string
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
            Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;

            String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();

            cookieManager.setCookie(ReferenceHolder.BASE_URL, cookieString);



            cookieSyncManager.sync();

        }
        cookieSyncManager.sync();

        System.out.println("COOKIEMAN" + cookieManager.getCookie(ReferenceHolder.BASE_URL));


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie can't include the semicolon, because the semicolon means separator in the cookie string. If you want this, please encode firstly.

Answer (score 0):

David Wasser and AnswerZhao's answer is right, and for my experience, you can just set each `key=value` use `setCookie` like this:

```
for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
            Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;
            // set first key=value
            String cookieStr = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue();
            cookieManager.setCookie(ReferenceHolder.BASE_URL, cookieStr);
            // set second key=value
            cookieStr = "domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
            cookieManager.setCookie(ReferenceHolder.BASE_URL, cookieStr);
            // set ... key=value

            cookieSyncManager.sync();

        }
```